# Initialization of a static constexpr class member of enum-class type by explicit conversion function

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, enum-class

I have a discrepancy between the behaviour of g++ 4.8.1 and clang++ 3.4.

I've got a class `A`, of literal type, that has an `explicit` `constexpr` conversion function to type `enum class E`.

Gcc allows me to initialize `constexpr` variables of type `E` from a constant expression of type `A` using the conversion function in some cases, but not when the variable is a static class member (`e2` below)

Clang rejects the initialization in all contexts (`e1`, `e2` and `e3`).

According to `[over.match.conv]p1` use of an explicit conversion function is OK here

```
enum class E { e };
struct A { explicit constexpr operator const E() const noexcept { return E::e; } };

constexpr E e1{A{}};                      // Gcc: OK, Clang: Error
struct B { static constexpr E e2{A{}}; }; // Gcc: Error, Clang: Error
void f() { static constexpr E e3{A{}}; }  // Gcc: OK, Clang: Error
```

I see a similar pattern when converting to another literal class type instead of an enum type - g++ rejects the initialization of `s1`, clang rejects the initialization of `s1`, `s2` and `s3`. I think these should be valid as well, as per `[over.match.copy]p1`.

```
struct S { constexpr S(){} constexpr S(const S&){}};
struct A { explicit constexpr operator S() const noexcept { return S(); } };

constexpr S s1{A{}};                      // Gcc: OK, Clang: Error
struct B { static constexpr S s2{A{}}; }; // Gcc: Error, Clang: Error
void f() { static constexpr S s3{A{}}; }  // Gcc: OK, Clang: Error
```

Which compiler, if either, is right?

---

**Edit:** A couple of interesting things to note:

1. The results are different between clang-3.4 and clang-svn, see comments below.
2. When using parens for the initialization instead of braces, there is still a difference between `e2`/`s2` and `e1`/`e3`/`s1`/`s3`, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daca396a63425c6b. gcc and clang-svn agree, but I'm not convinced that rejecting e2 and s2 is correct.

Comment: note that the first 3 examples compile correctly on [Clang 3.5 SVN](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd5bbd2f90fe7457)

Comment: @TemplateRex interesting, thanks

Comment: also note that using the `auto si = S(A{});` initialization form, also works for all three cases: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f23cd452086ef40 I have no clue why the `S()` syntax works when the `S{}` won't.

Comment: For `auto si = S(A{});` g++ also accepts all 3. For `auto ei = E{A{}}` , clang-3.5 SVN accepts all 3 and g++ rejects all 3.

Comment: @DyP true, but [that's a function declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)!

Comment: @je4d ouch, true. (It's also forbidden as an in-class member-initializer IIRC.)

Comment: About e2/s2 with parentheses: the syntax just doesn't allow `T x(v);` initialization of class members.

Comment: @hvd thanks - I'd just reached the same conclusion about 30 seconds ago after digging through the grammar; _member-declarator_ can only have a _brace-or-equal-initializer_ rather that any _initializer_

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, Clang appears to be correct in rejecting these.

The reason is that there is a bug in the C++11 standard in which `{}` doesn't work for copy constructors.  This is why `()` constructors work, but `{}` constructors don't.

Bjarne Stroustrup says under the [errata for his book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) that it's fixed in C++14

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this is applicable, so I've removed my previous comment. I think Bjarne is referring to issue [1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1467), which only applies to aggregates. My example struct has user-defined default c'tor and copy c'tor to stop it being an aggregate.

Comment: @je4d: I'm not sure that it doesn't apply.  It seems to me that [decl.init]p14 says that the init list in this case is construed as the creation of a temporary and then a type conversion.  If you omit the word "explicit" from your code, I think it will work, which seems to indicate that even though it's done at compile-time, the semantics seem that it's a two-step process.

Comment: What document are you using? `[dcl.init]p14` from C++11 (N3290) doesn't seem applicable here. By my reading, [over.match.copy], bullet point 2, sentence 2 says that explicit conversions should be considered here.

Comment: @je4d: At the moment, I'm using N3337, so there may well be differences, but I think it was just my error.  Seems to me that  is a List-initialization of e2 per `[decl.init.list]p3`, and also a List-initialization of a temporary A which is value-initialized.  Given that, `[over.match.copy]` should rule, and indeed substituting `e1` for `A{}` works.  I'd overlooked the sentence you mentioned and agree with your interpretation so it's still a mystery...